# For loop not executing in subscribe event

Tags: angular, typescript

I have one chat design in which on left there is a list of people and on clicking of any people, I am opening his chat history on right. So I need to send user details from one component to another using RXJS subscribe call. Now data is transferring successfully but the issue is, after receiving user detail through `subscribe` call in right component, I am calling one API to get users to chat history and wanted to show chats in that component, so for that, I need to add for loop in success response of API but `for` loop is not getting executing. Below is my right side component code.

```
` ngOnInit() {

    this.userProfileId = this.utilService.getCurrentLoginUserProfileId();
    if (this.userProfileId) {

      this.friendId = this.userDetail.userProfileId;
       // get users data
      this.utilService.onChangeUserDetailData.subscribe(data => {
      console.log('data', data);
      if (data) {
        this.userDetail = data;
        this.friendId = this.userDetail.userProfileId;
        this.sendUserOnlineSocket(data);


        // get chat history api
        this.getUsersChatData(data);
        }
    });

    }

// get users chat data
  getUsersChatData(user: any) {
    let postObj;
    if (user.chatRoomId) {
      postObj = {
        from_user: this.userProfileId,
        to_user: user.chatRoomId
      };
    } else if (user.userProfileId) {
      postObj = {
        from_user: this.userProfileId,
        to_user: user.userProfileId
      };
    }

    this.chatPageService.getChatData(postObj).then((res: any) => {
      console.log(' chat data res', res);
      if (res['status'] === 200) {
        if (res['data']['length'] > 0) {
          for (let i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
            console.log('message response', res[i]);
            if (res[i]['user_profile_id'] === this.userProfileId && res[i]['to_user_id'] === this.friendId) {
              this.messageData.push({ side: 'right side', data: res[i] });
            } else {
              this.messageData.push({ side: 'left side', data: res[i] });
            }
          }
          console.log('message data', this.messageData);
        }
        console.log('message data', this.messageData);
      }
      console.log('message data', this.messageData);
    }).catch(err => {
          if (err.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
            this.utilService.errorHandler(err.error);
          } else {
            this.utilService.showError(
              'Error',
              this.utilService.commonErrorMsg
            );
          }
    });
  }

`
```

I am successfully getting 'chat data res' console but in `for` loop I am getting 'message response' undefined and below consols are not getting executed. Please suggest me a solution for it or any other option to do this.

Comment: Have you checked the network tab in chrome dev tools to see what error status code is being returned by that http request. It might not be a 200 response. Please show the getChatData method in your question as well.

Comment: @LloydNicholson I am getting successful res . Also I am getting this console  console.log(' chat data res', res); but after that the below forloop is not working

Comment: @Annonymous you are doing a mistake.  console.log('message response', res.data[i]); please check the line you have console. the data object you need to retrieve at the position not res object. there is no res[i] because of this you got undefined in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code you are doing one mistake.

Instead of `res[i]` you need to check for `res.data[i]`

```
for (let i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
        console.log('message response', res.data[i]);             
 }
```

check above you will get your data and after this change, replace `res[i]['user_profile_id']` with `res.data[i]['user_profile_id']`. Do this change for your code wherever required

Comment: @Annonymous Tips: Instead of accessing `res['data']['length']` and `res.data` *two times* I would use `let data = res.data;` and then `data.length` and use the data variable throw entire execution!